# Terraform API Gateway multiple region deployment: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway, region

I am going for a modular approach to deploying APIgateway and associated lambda, across multiple regions (aws and aws.secondary provider). Assuming each var variable is assigned:

primary-gateway:

```
module "test_api" {
  source      = "./modules/api-gateway"
  name        = "test-api"
  description = "primary API"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id #vpc in primary region
  region      = var.region
  stage_name  = ""

  policy = <<EOF
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "execute-api:/*",
        "Condition": {
          "StringNotEquals": {
            "aws:sourceVpce": ["${data.aws_vpc_endpoint.execute_api_endpoint.id}"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "execute-api:/*"
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "Resource": ["${module.test_lambda.lambda_arn}"]
      }
    ]
  }
  EOF

}
data "aws_vpc_endpoint" "execute_api_endpoint" {
  vpc_id       = var.vpc_id
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.${var.region}.execute-api"
}


# --------------Endpoint and Authorization ------------------

module "post_endpoint" {
source = "./modules/api-gateway-endpoint"

rest_api_id      = module.test_api.api_id
root_resource_id = module.test_api.root_resource_id
path             = "test"
invoke_arn       = module.test_lambda.invoke_arn
lambda_name      = module.test_lambda.function_name
execution_arn    = module.test_api.execution_arn
http_method      = "POST"
authorizer_id    = aws_api_gateway_authorizer.gateway-authorizer.id
}
resource "aws_api_gateway_authorizer" "gateway-authorizer" {
  name                   = "test-gateway-authorizer"
  rest_api_id            = module.test_api.api_id
  authorizer_uri         = module.lambda_api_gateway_authorizer.invoke_arn
  authorizer_credentials = aws_iam_role.authorizer_invocation_role.arn
  identity_source        = "method.request.header.X-SF_AD_OIDC_TOKEN"
  type                   = "REQUEST"
}
module "lambda_api_gateway_authorizer" {
  source = "./modules/lambda"

  function_name        = "azureAuthorizer"
  policy_document_json = data.aws_iam_policy_document.lambda_api_gateway_authorizer.json
  account              = var.account  
  region               = var.region
    
  subnet_ids         = local.private_subnets
  security_group_ids = [local.https_outbound_sg_id]

  kms_key_arn          = var.kms_key_id
  permissions_boundary = var.permissions_boundary

}
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lambda_api_gateway_authorizer" {
  statement {
    actions = "*"
    resources = ["arn:aws:logs:${var.region}:${var.account}:log-group:/aws/lambda/*:*"]
  }

  statement {
    actions   = ["kms:Decrypt", "kms:Encrypt", "kms:GenerateDataKey"]
    resources = [var.kms_key_id]
  }

  statement {
    actions = [
      "ec2:DescribeInstances",
      "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
      "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
      "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
      "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
    ]

    resources = ["*"]
  }
}
resource "aws_iam_role" "authorizer_invocation_role" {
  name                 = "test-api-gateway-auth-invocation"
  path                 = "/"
  permissions_boundary = var.permissions_boundary

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

# --------------Stages and Deployment ------------------

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "test_api" {
  depends_on = [module.post_endpoint.endpoint_integration]

  rest_api_id = module.test_api.api_id
  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(join(
      "",
      [
        file("api-test-endpoint.tf") #endpoints are declared in this file
      ]
    ))
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "stage" {
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.test_api.id
  rest_api_id   = module.test_api.api_id
  stage_name    = "sandbox"
  access_log_settings {
    destination_arn = module.test_api.api_logs_arn
    format          = "{ \"requestId\":\"$context.requestId\", \"ip\": \"$context.identity.sourceIp\", \"caller\":\"$context.identity.caller\", \"user\":\"$context.identity.user\", \"requestTime\":\"$context.requestTime\", \"httpMethod\":\"$context.httpMethod\", \"resourcePath\":\"$context.resourcePath\", \"status\":\"$context.status\", \"protocol\":\"$context.protocol\", \"responseLength\":\"$context.responseLength\" }"
  }
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "test_api" {
  rest_api_id = module.test_api.api_id
  stage_name  = aws_api_gateway_stage.stage.stage_name
  method_path = "*/*"
}
module "test_lambda" {
  source = "./modules/lambda"

  function_name        = "testAPILambda"
  policy_document_json = data.aws_iam_policy_document.test_policy.json
  tags                 = local.common_tags
  workspace            = terraform.workspace
  account              = var.account
  region               = var.region

  subnet_ids         = local.private_subnets
  security_group_ids = [local.https_outbound_sg_id]

  kms_key_arn     = var.kms_key_id
  permissions_boundary = var.permissions_boundary

}
```

secondary-gateway:

```
module "test_secondary" {
  source      = "./modules/api-gateway"
  name        = "test-api"
  description = "Secondary API"
  vpc_id      = var.secondary_vpc_id
  region      = var.secondary_region
  stage_name  = ""
  providers    = { aws = aws.secondary }
  policy = <<EOF
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "execute-api:/*",
        "Condition": {
          "StringNotEquals": {
            "aws:sourceVpce": ["${data.aws_vpc_endpoint.execute_api_endpoint_secondary.id}"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "execute-api:/*"
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "Resource": ["${module.test_lambda_secondary.lambda_arn}"]
      }
    ]
  }
  EOF

}

data "aws_vpc_endpoint" "execute_api_endpoint_secondary" {
  vpc_id       = var.secondary_vpc_id
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.${var.secondary_region}.execute-api"
  provider = aws.secondary
}

# --------------Endpoint and Authorization ------------------

module "test_endpoint_secondary" {
  source = "./modules/api-gateway-endpoint"

  rest_api_id      = module.test_api_secondary.api_id
  root_resource_id = module.test_api_secondary.root_resource_id
  path             = "test"
  invoke_arn       = module.test_lambda_secondary.invoke_arn
  lambda_name      = module.test_lambda_secondary.function_name
  execution_arn    = module.test_api_secondary.execution_arn
  http_method      = "POST"
  authorizer_id    = aws_api_gateway_authorizer.gateway-authorizer-secondary.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_authorizer" "gateway-authorizer-secondary" {
  name                   = "test-gateway-authorizer-secondary"
  rest_api_id            = module.test_api_secondary.api_id
  authorizer_uri         = module.lambda_api_gateway_authorizer_secondary.invoke_arn
  authorizer_credentials = aws_iam_role.authorizer_invocation_role.arn
  identity_source        = "method.request.header.X-SF_AD_OIDC_TOKEN"
  type                   = "REQUEST"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "authorizer_invocation_policy_secondary" {
  name = "test-api-gateway-auth-invocation-policy-secondary"
  role = aws_iam_role.authorizer_invocation_role.id

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "${module.lambda_api_gateway_authorizer_secondary.lambda_arn}"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
 
module "lambda_api_gateway_authorizer_secondary" {
  source = "./modules/lambda"

  function_name        = "azureAuthorizer"
  policy_document_json = data.aws_iam_policy_document.lambda_api_gateway_authorizer_secondary.json
  account              = var.account
  region               = var.secondary_region
  providers            = { aws = aws.secondary }

  subnet_ids         = local.secondary_private_subnets
  security_group_ids = [local.https_outbound_sg_id_secondary]

  kms_key_arn     = var.kms_secondary_key_id
  permissions_boundary = var.permissions_boundary

}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lambda_api_gateway_authorizer_secondary" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "logs:CreateLogGroup",
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
      "logs:PutLogEvents",
      "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
      "logs:PutSubscriptionFilter"
    ]
    resources = ["arn:aws:logs:${var.secondary_region}:${var.account}:log-group:/aws/lambda/*:*"]
  }

  statement {
    actions   = ["kms:Decrypt", "kms:Encrypt", "kms:GenerateDataKey"]
    resources = [var.kms_secondary_key_id]
  }

  statement {
    actions = [
      "ec2:DescribeInstances",
      "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
      "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
      "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
      "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
    ]

    resources = ["*"]
  }
}

# --------------Stages and Deployment ------------------

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "test_secondary" {
  depends_on = [module.test_endpoint_secondary.endpoint_integration]

  rest_api_id = module.test_secondary.api_id
  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(join(
      "",
      [
        file("api-test-endpoint.tf")
      ]
    ))
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
  provider = aws.secondary
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "stage_secondary" {
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.test_secondary.id
  rest_api_id   = module.test_secondary.api_id
  stage_name    = "sandbox"
  access_log_settings {
    destination_arn = module.test_secondary.api_logs_arn
    format          = "{ \"requestId\":\"$context.requestId\", \"ip\": \"$context.identity.sourceIp\", \"caller\":\"$context.identity.caller\", \"user\":\"$context.identity.user\", \"requestTime\":\"$context.requestTime\", \"httpMethod\":\"$context.httpMethod\", \"resourcePath\":\"$context.resourcePath\", \"status\":\"$context.status\", \"protocol\":\"$context.protocol\", \"responseLength\":\"$context.responseLength\" }"
  }
  provider = aws.secondary
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "test_secondary" {
  rest_api_id = module.test_secondary.api_id
  stage_name  = aws_api_gateway_stage.stage_secondary.stage_name
  method_path = "*/*"
  provider = aws.secondary
}
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "test_permission_secondary" {
  statement_id  = "AllowAPIGatewayInvoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = module.test_lambda_secondary.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  source_arn = "${module.test_api_secondary.execution_arn}/*/*/*"
  provider = aws.secondary
}
module "test_lambda_secondary" {
  source = "./modules/lambda"

  function_name        = "testAPILambda-secondary"
  policy_document_json = data.aws_iam_policy_document.test_policy_secondary.json
  workspace            = terraform.workspace
  account              = var.account
  region               = var.secondary_region
  providers            = { aws = aws.secondary }

  subnet_ids         = local.secondary_private_subnets
  security_group_ids = [local.https_outbound_sg_id_secondary]

  kms_key_arn     = var.kms_secondary_key_id
  permissions_boundary = var.permissions_boundary

}
```

These are near identical except the secondary provider is given for the region.
I get this error:

> Error creating API Gateway: AccessDeniedException:   on modules\api-gateway\main.tf line 1, in resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api_gateway":
> 1: resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api_gateway" {

And this error **only** shows once the secondary resource is added.

Both resources are referencing this block template:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api_gateway" {
  name        = var.name
  description = var.description

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["PRIVATE"]
  }


  policy = var.policy
}

#  ------------- API Cloudwatch Logs --------------

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "api_logs" {
  name              = "test-apigateway-${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id}-access-logs"
  retention_in_days = 14
}
```

Any help for where this error can be found or what to look at is appreciated.

### Steps already taken:

- already added provider = aws.secondary to the secondary module
- broadened permissions for aws_lambda_permission
- checked if vpc ids were correct
- edited lambda policies to broaden permission

Comment: Yes this helped clarify my troubles. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but it seems to me that you are trying to create VPC interface endpoints to API gatway in a different region. If so, this is not supported. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpce-interface.html):

> Endpoints are supported within the **same Region only**. You cannot create an endpoint between a VPC and a service in a different Region.